# How can I explain to my boss that I am not able to complete a task?

Tags: career-development

I always had a knack for computers.  I started programming a few years back and was passionate enthusiastic at first.  In time, programming became less and less interesting to me so I decided to quit.

I decided that I still love computers and want to work in IT industry, so I enrolled in an Information Technology course in a university.  While at the university, I got a job at a computer repair company. Although I'm only the guy who takes in new orders, I guess that's something for a first job. I'm happy it's IT related.

My boss knows that I can program and offered for me to do a project for his company. Although I gave up programming I agreed, but not long after I again saw that programming is just not for me so I will have to decline the offer.

How can I communicate this to my employer so that it will minimize the conflict that may arise?  How can I explain to them that programming is not something I can do professionally?

Comment: @Yvad Welcome to the workplace. I have updated the question to make it acceptable to the Q&A format of this site.  I think the question asked will provide you with the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Related question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/226577/career-advice-not-sure-what-to-do

Comment: @atk: I'm not sure age is that relevant.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: the OP brought it up, so I was asking to determine if it is or not.  If s/he is 63 and getting ready to retire, that's different from a 55 year old winding down a career, or a 40 year old changing disciplines, or a 30 year old changing disciplines.

Comment: @atk - The first job thing would lead me to presume 20's at most... From p2 *Although I'm only the guy who takes in new orders, I guess that's something for a first job.*

Comment: @Chad good catch. I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

Be honest.  Tell him that although you made an honest effort, what he's looking for is beyond your expertise.

It may turn out good:

1. He'll know that you're not out to waste his time.
2. He'll know that you are honest.
3. He may offer to pay for the training you need to complete the task, or extend you much more time.  (DON'T ask for this.  If he offers, great.)

It may turn out bad:

1. He'll have a hard time trusting you.
2. Suspension or termination.

If it turns out bad, you don't need to be working for the guy anyhow if he reacts this way to someone new to the field.

Either way you can't control what he does.  Focus on what YOU do and if you are doing the right thing, you can feel good about that no matter what.

Comment: Good answer.  Additionally, the OP should help his boss find a qualified employee or contractor.  The OP may not know how to program, but probably understand the project and knows enough about programming to judge applicants.